# goto in Using statement, will the dispose be called?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, using, goto

Consider the following

```
using (Entity e = new Entity())
{
     goto: Mars
}
```

Do I have a leak?  Not that I'm gonna do such foolishness but just wondering.

Answer (score 2):

Yes `Dispose` will be called. `using` translates into `try/finally` block something like:

```
try
{
    goto Mars;
    Console.WriteLine("in try");
}
finally
{

    Console.WriteLine("in finally");
}
Mars:
Console.WriteLine("in Mars");
```

The output from above would be:

```
in finally
in Mars
```

You can also test it by creating your own class that implements `IDisposable` like:

```
class MyDisposable : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dispose called");
    }
}
```

and then:

```
using (MyDisposable myDisposable = new MyDisposable())
{
    goto Mars;
}

Mars:
Console.WriteLine("in Mars");
```

The output would be:

```
Dispose called
in Mars
```

Comment: Thank you.  Great info.  Now my life is complete. :)